# possible property for floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is it true that
$$ \left\lfloor \frac{p_n}{p_i\cdot p_j}\right\rfloor \leq 
   \left\lfloor \frac{p_n}{p_i}\right\rfloor \cdot \ \frac{1}{p_j}
$$
for $p_n$ prime, $p_i,p_j$ also primes for $i,j < n$ ? I think like so:
$$ \left\lfloor \frac{p_n}{p_i\cdot p_j} \right\rfloor =
   \left\lfloor
       \left\lfloor \frac{p_n}{p_i} \right\rfloor \
       \cdot\frac{1}{p_j}   
   \right\rfloor \leq 
   \left\lfloor \frac{p_n}{p_i} \right\rfloor \cdot \frac{1}{p_j}
$$ Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of the [well-known properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the floor function:

$$\Big\lfloor \frac{p_n}{p_ip_j}\Big\rfloor=\Big\lfloor\frac{\Big\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p_i}\Big\rfloor}{p_j}\Big\rfloor\le\frac{\Big\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p_i}\Big\rfloor}{p_j}=\Big\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p_i}\Big\rfloor\frac{1}{p_j}$$

The specific properties used are the [nested division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Nested_divisions) and that $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$